# keeping smileys/emoticons while removing special characters using regex python

Tags: python, regex, text, special-characters, emoticons

I am using the following code for cleaning my text

```
def clean_str(s):
"""Clean sentence"""
  s = re.sub(r"[^A-Za-z0-9(),!?\'\`]", " ", s)
  s = re.sub(r"\'s", " \'s", s)
  s = re.sub(r"\'ve", " \'ve", s)
  s = re.sub(r"n\'t", " n\'t", s)
  s = re.sub(r"\'re", " \'re", s)
  s = re.sub(r"\'d", " \'d", s)
  s = re.sub(r"\'ll", " \'ll", s)
  s = re.sub(r",", " , ", s)
  s = re.sub(r"!", " ! ", s)
  s = re.sub(r"\(", " ", s)
  s = re.sub(r"\)", " ", s)
  s = re.sub(r"\?", " ? ", s)
  s = re.sub(r"\s{2,}", " ", s)
  s = re.sub(r'\S*(x{2,}|X{2,})\S*',"xxx", s)
  s = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+', "", s)
  return s.strip()
```

As you can see that I am removing parentheses and other special characters. Now, I want to keep the following patterns intact in my text and not remove them

:), :-), :( and :-(

Could anyone help me with this please?

thanks,

Comment: At a minimum, you need to add `:` and `-` to the class in the first `re.sub`. Be sure to put the `-` at the end of the brackets otherwise it defines a range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ask yourself what patterns match any chars from the smilies you want to "protect". You can easily see that [`` r"[^A-Za-z0-9(),!?'`]" ``](https://regex101.com/r/aOKrdl/1), [`r"\("`](https://regex101.com/r/aOKrdl/2) and [`r"\)"`](https://regex101.com/r/aOKrdl/3) match these chars.

So, you may fix those patterns:

```
s = re.sub(r":-?[()]|([^A-Za-z0-9(),!?'`])", lambda x: " " if x.group(1) else x.group(), s) # Match smilies and match and capture what you need to replace
s = re.sub(r"(?<!:)(?<!:-)\(", " ", s) # Prepend (?<!:)(?<!:-) lookbehinds
s = re.sub(r"(?<!:)(?<!:-)\)", " ", s) # Prepend (?<!:)(?<!:-) lookbehinds
```

The `` :-?[()]|([^A-Za-z0-9(),!?'`]) `` pattern matches a smiley to protect (`:-?[()]` matches a `:`, then an optional `-` and then a `(` or `)`) or matches and captures into Group 1 any char other than the one defined in the negated character class. The `lambda x: " " if x.group(1) else x.group()` lambda expression implements a custom replacement logic depending on a group match: if Group 1 matched, the replacement occurs, else, the smiley is put back where it was.

The `(?<!:)(?<!:-)` negative lookbehinds make sure `(` and `)` are not matched if they are prepended with `:` or `:-`.

Note [`r'\S*(x{2,}|X{2,})\S*'`](https://regex101.com/r/aOKrdl/4) can also match the smilies if they are glued to the `xx` or `XX`. However, fixing this one is tricky since `:(` like smilies might be matched with `\S*` if they are not at the start of the non-whitespace chunk, so, you may use

```
s = re.sub(r'(:-[()])|(?:(?!:-?[()])\S)*(?:x{2,}|X{2,})(?:(?!:-?[()])\S)*',"xxx" if x.group(1) else x.group(), s)
```

The tactics is similar to `` r":-?[()]|([^A-Za-z0-9(),!?'`])" `` pattern, we match and capture the smiley, but then we only allow matching such non-whitespace chars (`\S`) that do not start the smiley substring (`(?:(?!:-?[()])\S)*`).

Comment: Thanks Wiktor! I have been struggling to understand how regex code works but somehow don't get it.  I still do not understand how you did it but it works. :-) (pun intended)

Comment: @ManojAgrawal I suggest re-reading the answer sentence by sentence, and please ask questions here in comments if you do not understand some concrete phrase or part of the code. I covered everything in the answer.